# chicken egg regexp

Tags: regex, perl

Assuming:

```
my $s1='A "sentence" ... is a concatination of nondelimiters followed by delimiters,
        followed by nondelimiters, followed by delimiters, ...';
```

or

```
my $s2='"A "sentence" ... is a concatination of delimiters followed by nondelimiters,
        followed by delimiters, followed by nondelimiters, ..."';
```

I try to split it by regexp to a list @a using a delimiter set in scalar $d:

```
my $d = ' ,."'; # delimiter set
my @a = $s1 =~ /([^$d]+)([$d]+)/g; # gives |A| "|sentence|" ... |is| |a| |...
```

In the second case the sentence on could use

```
my @a = $s2 =~ /([$d]+)([^$d]+)/g; # gives |"|A| "|sentence|" ... |is| |a|...
```

How can one handle both cases with a single regexp? Need help - please.

Comment: this does not work:
my @a = $s=~/([^$d]+)([$d]+)|([$d]+)([^$d]+)/g;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a continuous block of delimiters or nondelimiters. Just use

```
$s =~ /([$d]+|[^$d]+)/g;
```

Comment: Great that is what I have looked for - it works very well. Thank You @choroba.